# MySQL auto_inc reindex with foreign key

Tags: mysql, reindex

I have 2 tables, A and B.
A and B are have three columns.

Here is the structure of A:

```
id,name,phone
```

Here is the structure of B:

```
id,Aid,name
```

The "`Aid`" is related to "`id`" of table A. you know, foreign key.
The "id" of table A is `auto_inc`, but I want to reindex it and change "`Aid`" of table B at the same time.
How can I do?

Comment: you can add ON UPDATE CASCADE in your table B.

Comment: But reindexing is not really a good practice in general. PKs are supposed to be durable.

Comment: visit http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74627/difference-between-on-delete-cascade-on-update-cascade-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks for you guys.

Comment: Before doing anything, you should really question whether you know what you're doing. From the question you presented, it appears you aren't aware that you should **never**, in any circumstances, fiddle with the value of a primary key. You don't have to trust several people here who told you not to do it, it's your project and your application, but there are reasons we never touch primary keys. It's like fiddling with someone's DNA and expecting nothing will ever go wrong from doing so.